# Gtk Perl : remove default text in Text Entry without using a placeholder

Tags: perl, gtk, glade

While I am aware that `set_placeholder_text("I am the placeholder")` will solve my problem, this feature is only available from Gtk+ 3.2 onwards.

I would like to know the simplest method to remove the default text from a Text Entry box when the user clicks on it.

Comment: What exact minimum version of GTK+ do you need?

Comment: GTK+ 2 is the version I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `'focus-in-event'` signal is a satisfactory solution here. 
In the callback, set the text in the Text Entry box to `""` so that it is cleared when clicked on (i.e., when the Text Entry box gets *focus*).

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-focus